# How to make a separate toc in appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, titletoc

I want to have a table of contents in the appendix. My situation looks like this:

```
--rest of document--

\appendix
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\chapter{Title of appendix}
\stopcontents
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{ }{3}{}

\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}} % don't want appendix sections in main toc
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
some text blah blah blah
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\section{History}
some more text
\subsection{History2}
some more text 1234
\subsubsection{History3}
\section{Now}

\stopcontents[sections]
\end{document}
```

What command is used to add table of contents so that it will list sections History, History2, History3 and Now somewhere below the titlepage?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the following code does what you want.

The important part is

```
\printcontents[sections]{ }{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
```

which is your *appendix* `toc` which *does* include `sections`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{intro}
\lipsum
\chapter{other}
\lipsum
\chapter{other}
\lipsum
\appendix

\chapter{Title of appendix}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{ }{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
some text blah blah blah
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\section{History}
some more text
\subsection{History2}
some more text 1234
\subsubsection{History3}
\section{Now}

\stopcontents[sections]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea why printcontents does nothing?

Comment: @Dextter you'll need to be more specific - my MWE works as expected